# spoiler module doesn't work

Tags: 6, theming, nodes

I want to place one or many spoiler in a node, I mean I want to hide specific paragraph in a spoiler.

I used [Spoiler module](http://drupal.org/project/spoiler) but it didn't work, How can I use spoiler in Drupal 6 ?

Comment: I've not used the module so I'm not writing this as an answer, but I'm assuming it's a filter you apply to your input type.  Have you enabled this filter on your chosen input type (Full HTML, Filtered HMTL etc)?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it using a Javascript Spoiler, I'll post the answer soon.